# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python, request

I want to crawl a web page [freeproxylists.net](http://www.freeproxylists.net/zh/?c=&pt=&pr=HTTPS&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=60) but encontered the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    r = requests.get("http://www.freeproxylists.net/zh/?c=&pt=&pr=HTTPS&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=60", headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I add headers to the request as some answers suggested in some similar problems but it doesn't work. And some answers say it's the server's problem but the web page can be accessed in the browser. I think there must be something different in this site as the code works fine on some other sites.

Below is the simplified code that cause the problem

```
    headers = { 
    "Accept": "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Host": "www.freeproxylists.net",
    "Referer": "http://www.freeproxylists.net",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
}
r = requests.get("http://www.freeproxylists.net/zh/?c=&pt=&pr=HTTPS&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=60", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Can you add the following details, for documenting purposes, as your [mcve] does not raise this exception on my machine at the moment. `requests.__version__ ==  2.9.1`, python version == 3.4.3